# dependent picklist on vf page using apex:selectoption in force.com site

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, force.com-sites

We have a force.com Sites application for our customer portal, on one particular Visualforce page we have a set of dependent picklists displayed but we can't use apex:inputfield.
so need to use select option or by using javascript or by global describe

Anyone come across this before/have a workaround.